# Python regex in GAE

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to update my webapp2 router to take me to a different handler in a certain case here is what I have:

address: "*.com/blog/post?action=edit&id=fl2j3r0udflj3"

to keep it simple I want to just match on /blog/post?action=edit

I have this:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/',Redirect),
    (r'/blog/post?(\S+)', blog.EditPost),
    ('/blog/post', NewPost),
....
```

doesn't work.

I've tried several different things such as

1. ('r/blog/post\?action=edit', blog.EditPost)
2. ('r/blog/post\?action=edit(.*+)', blog.EditPost)

Nothing is working. Any ideas?

Comment: ?... is a query string, which is not part of the path. Get the action argument in your handler and call the action function.

Comment: Why are you constructing the URLs like that? It would be more idiomatic to use `/blog/post/<id>/edit`.

Comment: And use webapp2 extended routing to match the /blog/post/<id>/edit  request: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#extended-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: If you want to maintain your URL structure, your '/blog/post' handler is going to need to dispatch further based on presence parameters and their values.

This is one of those situations were it helps to have prior knowledge of what's meant by a 'path' when talking about URLs. Specifically, that parameters aren't part of the path.

It's also solvable by digging in to the SDK source, with the goal of answering the question "which part of the URL is being considered when matching routes?"

`webapp2` provides functionality on top of `webob`. `webapp2.WSGIApplication` builds a list of `webapp2.SimpleRoute`s for the routes passed to the `WSGIApplication` constructor. A `SimpleRoute` "matches" based on `request.path`, which is a property on the request provided by `webob.Request` (which `webapp2.Request` subclasses). The `path` property starts with

```
    @property
    def path(self):
        """The path of the request, without host or query string"""
```

Meaning, ultimately, that query strings aren't matchable by routes. (You could dig further in to code to confirm that.)

Comment: Thank you, I'm realizing I should just restructure my classes to be more broadly applicable instead of creating a new handler for each regex I might encounter.